# Javafx SceneBuilder not shareable or derby not connecting in .exe

Tags: java, javafx, derby, scenebuilder

So I am a new programmer in my second term of Java programming. The term is over, but some of us students turned in our final projects only to find out when we gave over our projects some of the .jar files do not seem to follow the project.

We did all of our work in Netbeans because these were the rules and when using SceneBuilder things went wonky.

The solutions I'm looking for are:

1. How can I share this project with my teacher and have it work on a different machine than mine, (I did make this into a .exe file and .jar file, not a complete solution).
2. If number 1 can't be done, how do I get my derby database to work in the .exe file?

When the .exe file executes the GUI pops up and I have full functionality as I would when running in Netbeans. Cool right? Ehh. Only problem is the derby database does not get built as it should.  Then the select statements do not get called, because there is no DB to connect to.

Any help would be amazing and if a solution for sharing the non .exe in Netbeans can work I think it will help my instructor also.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using derby in an Make sure you have derby.jar in your class path. Am assuming you are using derby in an embedded environment if not please clarify. Make sure you connection path points to the location of your database

Comment: The Java program is supposed to build the database upon inception. My only guess so far has is, the program can't build the database outside of Netbeans, but makes little sense to me. The derby.jar is in the library for the project and everything executes well in Netbeans IDE.

Comment: Could you post your code snippet so that i could see how you set up your data connection